How to calculate the probability of a random great circle in a sphere pass through a certain spherical cap?
at some point, I got lost in some calculations. So, there is a sphere and a spherical cap in it. Imagine a great circle (one that passes through the center of a sphere) is chosen at random. I want to find a formula that can give me the probability p that this great circle runs through the spherical cap. I thought a lot about it and I found two answers which I thought were reasonable, but they are different from each other, and I don't know if one of them is correct or if none is.
At first, I tried to picture the sphere as a globe, with the center of the spherical cap in the North Pole and the equator as the great circle that is perpendicular to the line connecting the poles. When thinking this way, we can see that the spherical cap consists of all the points above certain latitude, such as in all points above 60 degrees or π/3.
I wanted to make a formula that could give me the probability of any random great circle (one that passes through the center of the sphere) passing through the spherical cap above θ latitude.
One thing I noticed is that when we consider θ = 0, the probability is 1, and when θ = pi/2, the probability is 0. You can think about it and see that this is true.
So I noticed that every great circle should have a point in the sphere with maximum latitude, and if this point was above θ, it would pass through the spherical cap, otherwise it wouldn't. I also thought that there was an equal chance of any point above the equator being the maximum, so the probability could be expressed as a ratio of the area of the spherical cap by half the area of the sphere. In this case,
p = 2πrh/(2π*r^2)
p = h/r
Since h = r(1-sinθ),
p = 1-sinθ.
However, we could also think that any great circle would pass by exactly two points in the equator (except the equatorial circle itself), and that any of these points have the same probability of being passed by. I also thought that the angle in which the circle passes through the equator was random, so in any point, p would equal the latitude range of the spherical cap by the latitude range of half the circle. In this case,
p = 2(π/2-θ)/π
p = (π-2θ)/π
p = 1-2θ/π
In this case, I had two possibilities. Either p = 1-sinθ or p = 1-2θ/π. Both of these work for the critical points of θ = 0 or θ = π/2, but they are different functions. So could you help me find which of these, if any, is correct?

I believe the most natural (and symmetrical) way to introduce measure on the set of all great circles is to make it symmetrical (invariant) with respect to the actions of the group of rotations $SO(3)$. That is, it should utilize the Haar measure of that group.

Welcome to MSE! <> You don't explicitly say $\theta$ is the latitude of the boundary of the cap, but assuming that's the case and "randomly" means the normal line to the great circle is chosen randomly with respect to area on the sphere, the probability is indeed $1-2\theta/\pi$. <> (Added: Which formula is correct does depend on what exactly is intended by random.)
